# How to fill \makenonemptybox like a checkered page (3 mm) or lined page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam

I would like to fill every \makenonemptybox like a checkered page (3 mm) or lined page?

That's my code.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5} 
\frenchspacing 
 \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{enumerate}

 \usepackage{multicol}

     \usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\pointpoints{p.}{p.}
\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}

\begin{document}
\large 
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi




\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
\centering
{\textbf{Exam}}
\end{minipage}


\end{center}

 \begin{questions}

\question[3] question 1

\makenonemptybox{1.3in}{

}

\question question 2:

\makenonemptybox{1.3in}{

}


\end{questions}





{ \small
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{Question}
  \hpword{Points}
  \bhpword{Bonus Points:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot. Points}}
  \hsword{Points}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
}
  }



}




\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by "like a checkered page (3 mm) or lined page?"? Do you want a `checkerboard` and/or `horizontal line` pattern as described on p. 718 of the pgfmanual?

Comment: Ok. I'll add a pic! sorry but my english is weak sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this but I am wondering if you look for something like this.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5} 
\frenchspacing 
 \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{enumerate}

 \usepackage{multicol}

     \usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\pointpoints{p.}{p.}
\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\newcommand{\checkerboardbox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\path[pattern=checkerboard light gray] 
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\gridbox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\draw[very thin,gray]
(path picture bounding box.south west) grid[step=5mm]
(path picture bounding box.north east);
\draw (path picture bounding box.south west) grid[step=1cm]
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{sparse horizontal lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{5mm}}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{6mm}}%
{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{0.5pt}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}%
}%

\newcommand{\hlinebox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\path[pattern=sparse horizontal lines,pattern color=gray] 
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\large 
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi




\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
\centering
{\textbf{Exam}}
\end{minipage}


\end{center}

 \begin{questions}

\question[3] question 1

\makenonemptybox{1.3in}{

}
\gridbox{1.3in}{

}

\hlinebox{1.3in}{

}

\question question 2:

\makenonemptybox{1.3in}{

}


\end{questions}





{ \small
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{Question}
  \hpword{Points}
  \bhpword{Bonus Points:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot. Points}}
  \hsword{Points}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version without `\dimexpr` in the `tikz` codes.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5} 
\frenchspacing 
 \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{enumerate}

 \usepackage{multicol}

     \usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\pointpoints{p.}{p.}
\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\newcommand{\checkerboardbox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\path[pattern=checkerboard light gray] 
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=#1-2*\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\linewidth-2*\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\gridbox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\draw[very thin,gray]
(path picture bounding box.south west) grid[step=5mm]
(path picture bounding box.north east);
\draw (path picture bounding box.south west) grid[step=1cm]
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=#1-2*\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\linewidth-2*\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{sparse horizontal lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{5mm}}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{6mm}}%
{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{0.5pt}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}%
}%

\newcommand{\hlinebox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[path picture={\path[pattern=sparse horizontal lines,pattern color=gray] 
(path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle
(path picture bounding box.north east);},draw,minimum width=\linewidth,
minimum height=\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep,align=left,
text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]
{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\large 
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi




\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
\centering
{\textbf{Exam}}
\end{minipage}


\end{center}

 \begin{questions}

\question[3] question 1

\gridbox{1.3in}{

}


\question question 2:

\hlinebox{1.3in}{

}


\end{questions}





{ \small
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{Question}
  \hpword{Points}
  \bhpword{Bonus Points:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot. Points}}
  \hsword{Points}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I compiled the code and there is an error "You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode }" how can i fix it? thanks!

Comment: @ryuk I did not get these errors when compiling the above code... but I added a version without `\dimexpr` in the tikz code.

Comment: thanks a lot! today i'm unlucky...:( why this error "Missing \endgroup inserted \end{document}"?

Comment: @ryuk I do not know. Did you copy the full code as is and run it?

Comment: yes i did...it's very strange

Comment: It works only if i comment the %\hlinebox{1.3in}{
%
%}